# How to take and at a same time dumb an unwanted input? (scanf)

Tags: c

I have came across a little problem while I am playing around with `scanf` ... to be more specific, I would like to read the whole input and then ignore the rest. let me show you what do i mean:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int number_of_iterations = 1;
    int circles = 0;

    scanf("%d", &number_of_iterations);
    unsigned int chr[number_of_iterations][8];

    while (number_of_iterations > circles) {
        scanf("%x", chr[circles]);
        circles++;
    }

    int circles2 = 0;
    while (circles2 < circles){
        printf("%x \n", chr[circles2]);
        circles2++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This will take an X number of inputs, but if i put in input something like this:

```
1 1CAAC

      28    EAAEB5
  F489AD95
  CAAC

   28    EAAEB5
F489AD95 F489AD95 EAAEB5
F489AD95 F489AD95
```

input will take `1 1CAAC` but i want the rest to read but throw away... is there any function to do so ?

```
Dominiks-MacBook-Pro-2:testing stylez$ ./a.out
1 1CAAC

      28    EAAEB5
  F489AD95
  CAAC

   28    EAAEB5
F489AD95 F489AD95 EAAEB5
F489AD95 F489AD95e30ca8c0Dominiks-MacBook-Pro-2:testing stylez$ 
Dominiks-MacBook-Pro-2:testing stylez$       28    EAAEB5
bash: 28: command not found
Dominiks-MacBook-Pro-2:testing stylez$   F489AD95
bash: F489AD95: command not found
Dominiks-MacBook-Pro-2:testing stylez$   CAAC
bash: CAAC: command not found
Dominiks-MacBook-Pro-2:testing stylez$ 
Dominiks-MacBook-Pro-2:testing stylez$    28    EAAEB5
bash: 28: command not found
Dominiks-MacBook-Pro-2:testing stylez$ F489AD95 F489AD95 EAAEB5
bash: F489AD95: command not found
```

---

***Edited code from one ansser ( testing the code to understand how does it work )***

```
#include <stdio.h>

int consume_line(void) {
    int ch;
    while ((ch = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n') && ch != EOF) {
        ;
    }
    return ch;
}

int main(void)
{
    int number_of_iterations = 1;
    int circles = 0;

    int cnt;
    switch (scanf("%d", &number_of_iterations)) {
        case 1: consume_line(); break;
        case 0: consume_line(); /* Decide if code should re-try reading, etc. */ break;
        case EOF:
            printf("hello");// Decide what to do if End-Of-File or rare Low-Level-Input-Error occurred.
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No, there's no *function* that can read your mind and know what parts of that you want to use and what you want to ignore. You'll have to write the code to do that yourself. Compilers have gotten pretty smart, but there are none yet that are telepathic. FWIW, the usual way to write your `while` would be `while (circles < number_of_iterations)` - it's much easier to read and understand.

Comment: That terminal output doesn't come from the code you've posted, since the code you've posted doesn't output anything. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: edited with full code

Comment: regarding: `unsigned int chr[number_of_iterations][8];`  since this is declaring an array of `int`, that trailing `8` is 8 integers, not 8 characters.  I.E. each line of the array is '8 * sizeof( int )' bytes wide

Comment: I am going to change it to char dont worry about that, the problem I care about, is that I want to parse and then throw away input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would like to read the whole input and then ignore the rest.

Do not use `scanf()`, but do all user input with `fgets()` and then use `sscanf(), strtol()`, etc to parse.

If obliged to stay with `scanf()`, test its return value and consume the rest of the line.

```
int consume_line(void) {
  int ch;
  while ((ch = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n'  && ch != EOF) {
    ;
  }
  return ch;
}


....
switch (scanf("%d", &number_of_iterations)) {
   case 1: consume_line(); break;
   case 0: consume_line(); /* Decide if code should re-try reading, etc. */ break;
   case EOF: // Decide what to do if End-Of-File or rare Low-Level-Input-Error occurred.
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, may I ask what should be inside of that while ? -thank you

Comment: @StyleZ In the `while` loop, do `;` which is nothing.  Code will continue reading until `'\n'` or `EOF`.

Comment: I am really sorry but I have got an error trying to compile it ( i am new at it :D ) so this is really a dumb question, but still i ve got this error and I have no clue what to do with it : main.c:9:44: error: expected identifier
    while ((ch = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n') && (ch != EOF)) {
                                           ^ ( its pointing on ( ch ...

Comment: Tip: Avoid "I have no clue".  Rather than exaggerate and say what you cannot do, state what you can do and have observed.

Comment: also one more thing error ( i have assumed that it will be raised, but i am not sure what to parse there / hwo to hande it ) -> `undeclared label 'ch'`

Comment: nope, you have it there, but you have it just inicialised as an int, you dont pass it to the function or anything

Comment: Sorry, your unposted code is unclear - take some time to work it out.

Comment: I am gonna put down edited version of the whole code :) to make it look more clear

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189562/discussion-between-stylez-and-chux).